# How do you access a nested usercontrol viewmodel from the parent

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a usercontrol say a keypad which I want to reuse in several other controls. The keypad responds to INotifyPropertyChanged but I want to capture the changes in the parent control to update a textbox in it.

I was trying to access the control from the parent viewmodel but this isn't the correct way to do this with MVVM.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing ideas a bit I think.

The MVVM way would be to have two viewmodels, and two views.

`MasterControlViewModel` & `MasterControlView`

`KeypadControlViewModel` & `KeypadControlView`

`MasterControlViewModel` would subscribe to key events fired in `KeypadControlViewModel`.

However, you seem to be inferring that `KeypadControl` is just a standard control, without its own viewmodel. This would make sense given its close relation to the view (it's providing keyboard input, where inserts would depend on where the cursor is etc). If this is the case, it might be more appropriate for `KeypadControl` to have a "Target" dependency property that can be bound to an edit control in your `MasterControlView`. When a key is clicked, the `KeypadControl` just updates the target control, or, probably better, it could just fire keyboard RoutedEvents which would travel up the visual tree just like a real keyboard event, whcih foregoes the need for a target property.

This way all your input stuff gets handled in the view, and the `MasterControlViewModel` only cares about the fact that the string has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, if you want to do it MVVM style, than the keypad control should expose an ICommand property, with the command itself provided by the parent, and execute that command whenever a key is clicked.

The command will get the key clicked in the command parameter.

The actual command implementation will be in the parent control (you can use the [RelayCommand pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) for that) and can then update its TextBox.

The keypad class should include something like this:

```
class Keypad : UserControl
{
     ...
     public DependencyProperty OnKeypadKeyClickedCommandProperty = ... ;
     ...
     void OnZeroButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         OnKeypadKeyClickedCommand.Execute(this, new SomeKeyIdentifier('0'));
     }
     ...
}
```

The XAML should include something like this:

```
<local:Keypad OnKeypadKeyClickedCommand="{Binding HandleKeypadKeyClickCommand, ElementName=parentControlName}" />
```

And the implementation in the parent control should look something like this:

```
class ParentControl : ...
{
    DependencyProperty HandleKeypadKeyClickCommand = ...;

    void Init()
    {
        HandleKeypadKeyClickCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<SomeKeyIdentifier>(DoKeyPress));
    }
    ...
    void DoKeyPress(SomeKeyIdentifier key)
    {
         _Textbox.Text += key.Char;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Itai, but wouldn't this mean that I would have to provide an ICommand for each keypad button in every control that I nest it in?

Comment: No. As I said, you pass the clicked key in the command parameter, yielding only one command you need to provide.

Comment: OK. But how do you provide the command from the parent? I'm currently using RelayCommand in the keypad to get the values i.e. return _ButtonZeroPress ?? (_ButtonZeroPress = new RelayCommand<object>(DoButtonPress));

Comment: Ahhh. Hang on. Do you bind that button to a command in the parent i.e. in teh XAML?

Comment: Instead of doing `_ButtonZeroPress = new RelayCommand<object>(DoButtonPress));` you can do `_KeypadButtonPress = new RelayCommand<SomeKeyIdentifier>(DoButtonPress);` and have `DoButtonPress` look something like: `void DoButtonPress(SomeKeyIdentifier key) { _textBox.Text += key.KeyString; }`. Expose `_KeypadButtonPress` as a property or a dependency property so you can bind to it in XAML.

Comment: Of course if you prefer doing it by code you can always set the command, rather than bind it.

Comment: Itai, that I understand and thanks. But DoButtonPress is in the keypads viewmodel not the parent controls.

Comment: I'm trying to get the parent to subscribe to and event that the child fires. But the child is added via the XAML so the parent doesn't know about it.

Comment: So don't try to subscribe to an event. Use the command pattern I showed you above. Another thing you can do is give the child control a name and then subscribe in code, but that is far less nice.